# VS-code prettier extension removing perentheses

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, prettier

hello guys i need help with my code when i add perentheses prettier keeps on removing them, i did a little research and added .prettierrc in my root directory with the folloing:

```
 {
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "removeParens": false
     }
```

i am trying to add perentheses around my operation but it is not letting me

```
const modulo = (a, b) => {
  return ((a * 10) % (b * 10)) / 10;
};
const divide = (a, b) => {
  return (a * 10) / (b * 10) / 10;
};
const multiply = (a, b) => {
  return (a * 10 * (b * 10)) / 100;
};
const subtraction = (a, b) => {
  return (a * 10 - b * 10) / 10;
};
const addition = (a, b) => {
  return (a * 10 + b * 10) / 10;
};
```

any help???
i tried to add perentheses around my functions but prettier isnt allowing me, for some reason it is allowing my first function to work but not other function

Comment: Which parentheses is it removing?

Comment: modulo function is the perfect example of what i want my other functions to be but it wont allow me

Comment: Is that what you typed, or what prettier did to it?

Comment: thats what prettier did to it, modulo is fine, it's what i did, but when i redo it to the other functions it doesn't allow me and reverts it back to what i posted instead of what i want like in the modulo function

Comment: I don't see `removeParens` as an option in the [documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options)

Comment: The only option related to parentheses is `arrowParens`, which controls whether parentheses are put around the parameter list when there's only one parameter.